# Comparing String-based java enums

Tags: java, string, enums

I have an Enum defined as follows.

```
enum Status {
            PENDING("PENDING"),
            ABANDONED("ABANDONED"),
            PROCESSED("PROCESSED");

            private String value;
            private ReflectionStatus(String valueParam) {
                value = valueParam;
            }

            public String getValue() {
                return value;
            }                    
        }

Status status; 
// followed by code that sets status
```

My question is, if I use `if(status.equals(Status.PENDING))`, do I need to override equals in the Status enum?

Comment: If the enum name and the string are supposed to be always the same, then you don't need the string value. In the code you can simply `if (status == Status.PENDING) ...`

Comment: No you can not override the equals method of enum. And there is no need to do it.

Comment: Your arguments are exactly the same as what an enum would return when you get the `.name()` of it; no need for the argument here. Also, see `.valueOf()`.

Answer (score 1):

- You can not override the equals method of enum.
- Here no need to override it.
- You can directly use status == Status.PENDING.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply compare enum instances with ==:

```
if (status == Status.PENDING)
```

You can also do a switch on an enum.